# Windows universal app in VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-10, win-universal-app

Is it possibility to create windows universal app for windows 10 in Visual Studio 2013? Should I install some kind of SDK, and after that everything will be ok or I have to use VS2015?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS2013 won't work, you have to use VS2015.
You can run VS2015 on Windows 10, Windows 8.1 or Windows 7 to create Windows 10 apps.
Make sure to install the components for Windows Universal App Development during the installation of VS 2015.  VS 2015 can be installed side by side with VS 2013.

<sup>More info can be found on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx)</sup>

Comment: thanks I just found that information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn975273.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No need to have 2015. Not everyone is having this.

If you are using a different development environment than Visual Studio 2015, you can download a standalone Windows SDK for Windows 10 installer. Note that you don’t need to install this SDK if you’re using Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 – it's already included.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads

Below is the link for SDK

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=822845

Ramprasad.